# Referencing fields from other models

Tags: python, django, django-models

in my first journey into the django world I am trying to have a models unicode function reference another models unicode function with foreign key references. This is what I have and it's not working

```
class Rider(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):  
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

class Ride(models.Model):
    ride_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ride_meeting_place = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    ride_description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    ride_leader = models.ForeignKey(Rider)
    ride_date = models.DateTimeField('date of ride')
    ride_miles = models.FloatField('scheduled miles')
    def __unicode__(self):  
        return self.ride_name

class Miles(models.Model):
    rider_id = models.ForeignKey(Rider)
    ride_id = models.ForeignKey(Ride)
    actual_miles = models.FloatField('actual miles')
    def __unicode__(self):  
        return self.rider_id + " " + self.ride_id + " " + self.actual_miles
```

The last line is the one I'm having trouble with.

Comment: When you say "It's not working", what, specifically, do you mean?

Comment: The error was `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Rider' and 'str'
` Solved it now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tidy up your models a bit:

```
class Rider(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):  
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

class Ride(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    meeting_place = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    leader = models.ForeignKey(Rider)
    date = models.DateTimeField('date of ride')
    miles = models.FloatField('scheduled miles')
    def __unicode__(self):  
        return self.name

class Miles(models.Model):
    rider = models.ForeignKey(Rider)
    ride = models.ForeignKey(Ride)
    actual_miles = models.FloatField('actual miles')
    def __unicode__(self):  
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.rider, self.ride, self.actual_miles)
```

No need to preface all of your `Ride` fields with `ride_`.

Don't call your foreign key `rider_id`, just use `rider` (same with `ride_id`)

Then force the unicode by using a string formatter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add `_id` prefix:

```
class Miles(models.Model):
    rider = models.ForeignKey(Rider)
    ride = models.ForeignKey(Ride)
    actual_miles = models.FloatField('actual miles')

    def __unicode__(self):  
        return "%s %s %s" % (self.rider, self.ride, self.actual_miles)
```

By using string formatting, you are actually joining `str(self.rider)`, `str(self.ride)` and `str(self.actual_miles)`, which means calling `self.rider.__unicode__()` and `self.ride.__unicode()__` under the hood. Quote from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__unicode__):

> If you define a `__unicode__()` method on your model and not a `__str__()`
>   method, Django will automatically provide you with a `__str__()` that
>   calls `__unicode__()` and then converts the result correctly to a UTF-8
>   encoded string object. This is recommended development practice:
>   define only `__unicode__()` and let Django take care of the conversion
>   to string objects when required.

Comment: Have it fixed now thanks, but to clarify: Had I put each field in a `str()` function it would behave as intended? the original error I received was `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Rider' and 'str'
`

Comment: @dzanot yup, you could have put it in `str()` instead.